# qa.sockets.stackexchange.com never finishes loading

Tags: bug

Chrome shows the "loading" spinner for RPG SE endlessly for me. Taking a look in                                                                       Chrome's dev-tools shows wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com as Status 101 Switching Protocols and Time as Pending.

Google Chrome version 37.0.2062.124 m

...and now I've stopped seeing this behavior, literally as I posted this.

And it's back again. And it only happens at meta.rpg and rpg, not other SE sites.

Comment: Better move this to the whole network meta?

Comment: Have you observed this behavior on any of the other network sites?

Comment: @C.Ross No, and I'm seeing it here again, too.

Comment: @Zachiel No, because it seems to happen only here.

Comment: I'm not experiencing anything of the sort.

Comment: @KRyan I'm not totally sure about what should be done, but it still looks like a problem with the site as a whole (the programming part is not managed by us, unless you installed some script made by people on RPG.SE), despite being in a localized part of the site. The people who does the programming are, IMO, ulikely to see it here (unless they get linked)

Comment: @Zachiel The devs _do_ look at bugs and feature requests from child metas just the same. Since it's only happening on this site, it's appropriate to have this here. (I'm going to ask on Meta SE to check.)

Comment: I got confirmation: [bugs do get noticed on here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240568/152515)

Comment: Fine, and nice to know